# Цвет линии графика в plotly python

Tags: python, plotly

Всем привет!

Есть две линии в графике. ОсьX-время, осьY-глубина погружения. В зависимости от времени проходит определенная фаза работы. Как в plotly раскрасить линию под каждую фазу? В документации ничего подобного именно для линий не нашел, есть только для точек.

```
# well_a_data.RelatedPhase
# well_b_data.RelatedPhase

well_a_trace = go.Scatter(
    x = well_a_data.Days,
    y = well_a_data.HoleDepth,
    mode = 'lines',
    name = well_a_name
)
well_b_trace = go.Scatter(
    x = well_b_data.Days,
    y = well_b_data.HoleDepth,
    mode = 'lines',
    name = well_b_name
)
```

[image: график]

[image: линия+точки]

Comment: Разбейте массив точек на фазы и рисуйте отдельно каждую фазу нужным цветом)

Comment: То есть как это? `line=dict(color='red', width=1)` в параметры go.Scatter

Comment: Была такая идея, но на R в ggplot это делается одним параметром и красиво в виде градиента) Неужели в plotly нет такого?
Я совместил линию и маркер, но это не то. Очень странно, что можно так сделать с маркерами, но нельзя с линией

Comment: Исходя из сообщений в сообществе, пока нельзя реализовать такую штуку для линий https://community.plot.ly/t/streamline-plot-with-color-gradient/21207